# ASP.Net GridView Web Control Format Columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to format columns in the GridView control by placing code inside the DataBound event.  It doesn't work, because for some reason the columns collection is not populated.  The control is bound, it works, but yet the columns collection is showing a count of zero, and so the code doesn't work.
Ideas?

```
        protected void gvReport_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= gvReport.Columns.Count - 1; columnIndex += 1)
        {
            var col = ((BoundField)gvReport.Columns[columnIndex]);

            if (object.ReferenceEquals(col.DataField.GetType(), typeof(System.DateTime)))
                col.DataFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns generated with `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` are not available in the `Columns` collection of the GridView. You can process the cells in the `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void gvReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            object value = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[i];

            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[i];
                cell.Text = ((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```